# How to end if statement in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm learning python.
I have touched on other programming languages ​​for example:
PHP, HTML, C #, C ++ etc. But I could not understand Python a bit from the programming languages ​​I listed
Uses {}
When I try to start an if statement in Python I will have to start with : but I can not find a way to end it.
I mean, if the if statement is activated, some code must be executed, so I can not find a way to see which code will be executed when the if statement is activated.
I'm 11 years old.
This might be really bad question for python programers that because I'm currently learning python

Comment: If this isn't explained in your tutorial, I strongly suggest that you find a better one. A short list can be found here: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: You _dedent_ the first line that should not be part of the suite. Indentation has meaning in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python what you have to understand about block of code, is just indentation. check the following example:

```py
if 10 > 20:
   print('Inside if statement')
print('Outside if statement')
```

And the same goes to loop, function, class,...
In c#, c++, c we use {} to define a block of code but in python is just indentation